# What does "-" mean inside [ ] in regular expression?

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I was trying to match 
"**kit - kat**" or 
"**kit-kat**"
for one of my ElasticSearch project.

and I wanted it to become "**kitkat**".
So i was writting an char_filter.

To achieve the above mentioned result i was writing a Regular Expression in https://regex101.com

First i wrote a REGEX which looked like this "**(\S+)[ |-|_]***".

It didn't worked as expected (wrong expectation!).

But when i did this it worked "**(\S+)[ |\-|_]***".

What is the meaning of - in []?

Comment: In `[...]`, `-` defines a range

Comment: Thanks a lot. I finally got it.

Comment: If it is a Lucene engine, the hyphen at the start of the character class is treated as a literal `-`. At any other position in the character class, it must be escaped.

Comment: that is kind of weird.